# How to assign an ID to a entity in a Google AuoML natural language entity extraction model?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nlp, named-entity-recognition, google-cloud-automl, google-natural-language

How to give assign an ID to the entities added into AutoML Natural Language entity recognition model. For example, I Have added an entity "Chelsea" under "Sports" Label. How will I assign "Chelsea" an ID, so that whenever an article with an entity "Chelsea" comes in, it gets auto-tagged to a database?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/quickstart) which will be helpful in explaining how AutoML Natural Language works.

Basically, you are labeling your entities by category, and then an ML model will be built to recognize when a word or phrase should fall within that category -- even one's you haven't labeled. You are not building a list of future labeled entities to extract from text, that would be a simple algorithm and not machine learning.